# Why my app crashes everytime i try to load my onboarding layout?

Tags: android

I'm currently developing a small game with cards about Pokemon cards for class, and im facing a really weird issue.
I have a onboarding as a mini-tutorial for new users that only pops-up in the first run of the application but the issue is that in some devices it crashes and never shows up while in others it does.
I checked the console for this weird issue and the error i get is this one:
[Onboard error in console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eyxmw.png)

Not sure what to do, it works in one of my friends devices that is a Honor 8X but crashes in my Redmi note 9S also on a S10e and S21.
As extra, it does work in my Phone emulators inside android studio.
The only difference between the 3 is that my emulators and my friend's mobile are using API 29 while the others are on API 30, not sure if it had a lot to do with it but i guess it might help mentioning it.

Thanks and hopefully i can find a fix :D.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to find the issue.
It was one of the libraries i was using for load my gif images, apparently in the version i was using it cause this weird issue with permissions that lead to that error i showed in my original message.
For fix it, i just used the lastest version of the library, in case anyone have the same error the librarie itself was:

```
'pl.droidsonroids.gif:android-gif-drawable:1.2.+'
```

:)